# Native JPA query and SQL query not giving the same result

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have 2 tables: one called `issues` and the other is `time_entries` which have `id_issue` as foreign key. I made an INNER JOIN based on the `id_issue` column.

```
SELECT
    SUM(time_entries.hours)
    , issues.id
    , time_entries.created_on
    , time_entries.updated_on
    , issues.`estimated_hours`
    , issues.`done_ratio`
FROM
    issues
INNER JOIN
    time_entries
ON
    issues.id = time_entries.issue_id 
WHERE
    issues.project_id = 2
GROUP BY
    issues.id
```

I put this query in a native query:

```
Query query = (Query) this.em.createNativeQuery(
              "SELECT " +
              "    SUM(time_entries.hours) " +
              "    , issues.id " +
              "    , issues.estimated_hours" +
              "    , issues.done_ratio" +
              "FROM " +
              "    issues " +
              "INNER JOIN " +
              "    time_entries " +
              "ON " +
              "    issues.id = time_entries.issue_id " +
              "WHERE " +
              "    issues.project_id = 2 " +
              "GROUP BY " +
              "   issues.id");
List<?> result = query.getResultList();
```

When i execute those 2 lines of Java code, I don't get the same result as executing this query in MySQL console but I got the same query in the trace.

Comment: it would help if you told us how those 2 results differ

Comment: both do not display the same rows

Comment: you already mentioned that. You might Need to give us a Little more info